# Hiding .js and .js.map files in Visual Studio typescript compilation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I have a project build using Visual studio 2017 angular template. when i add a typescript file in visual studio 2017 and compile the project, i do not see any generated .js or js.map file under typescript file(s). but when i add a typescript file in Visual Studio 2019 and compile i see a .js and js.map file generated under typescript file. which means i 'll have to specifically exclude these files from being committed to source control.

I want to know how i can hide .js and js.map files in visual studio 2019 ? and why these files are being generated automatically in visual studio 2019 but not being generated in visual studio 2017.

Comment: Set up TS to generate those file in a dist/ folder, then simply add the folder to your gitignore

Comment: I see this is already in place and works with VS 2017. but when i add a .ts file through VS 2019 this file is also being added to .csproj

 <ItemGroup>
 <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\src\app\actions\my-test5.action.ts" />
 </ItemGroup>
 
 which i guess cause unwanted .js and js.map being generated. 

 This option is set in .csproj.

 <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>

 I am not sure why this behaviour is happening in VS 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Two options are available to you:
1. Configure TypeScript to generate output files (`.js` & `.js.map`) into a separate folder (like `/dist/` or `/build/`);
2. Add `*.js` & `*.js.map` to `.gitignore`, so they won't be added to source control

#### Option 1:

Add the following lines of code to your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/"
  }
}
```

#### Option 2:

Add the following lines of code to your `.gitignore` file:

```
*.js
*.js.map
```

Comment: I see Option 1 is already in place and works with VS 2017. but when i add a .ts file through VS 2019 this file is also being added to .csproj

 <ItemGroup>
 <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\src\app\actions\my-test5.action.ts" />
 </ItemGroup>
 
 which i guess cause unwanted .js and js.map being generated. 

 This option is set in .csproj.

 <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>

 I am not sure why this behaviour is happening in VS 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in tsconfig.json file:

```
"compileOnSave": false
```

Add this in .csproj file:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>False</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
```

Answer (score -2):

What about the exclude function in VScode settings?
Put it in user settings if you want the same for every project.

Just like this:

```
"files.exclude" : {
    "*.js": true,
    "*.js.map": true
}
```